# I am trying to sort List of String array. I used Collection.sort method but answer is wrong

Tags: java, android

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator < String[] > () {
    public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
        return  (strings[1].compareTo(otherStrings[1]));
```

I wrote this code. but answer is..

1
11
12
19
2
3
4
5
6
7

Can anyone tell me how to solve this

Comment: do you have a list of arrays???

Comment: I have List<String[]> a;

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't, but I can't help but wonder - why are you comparing the second elements in the string arrays?

Answer (score 6):

This is not wrong. That's the default ordering of Strings - lexicographical order.
If you want to sort the Strings by their numerical representation, convert them to integers first.

For example :

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String[]> () {
    public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
        return Integer.valueOf(strings[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(otherStrings[1]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom comparator

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        int l= Integer.parseInt(lhs);
        int r= Integer.parseInt(rhs);
        return l<r?1:l==r?0:-1;
    }
}
```